# Select distinct entries?

Tags: entries, relations

Here is my situation: I have a bunch of different series (which are each stored in a channel), and there are a bunch of sermons related to each series.

What I need to do is display the most recent entry of each series. Typically I would do this in a SELECT DISTINCT SQL query; How should I go about doing it in Craft?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question and structure correctly, then this might work.

```
{% entries = craft.entries.section('series').limit(null) %}
{% mostRecentSermons = [] %}

{% for entry in entries %}

    {# retrieve most recent sermon related to series #}
    {% set sermon = craft.entries.section('sermons').relatedTo(entry).order('postDate desc').first %}

    {# merge sermon into mostRecentSermons array #}
    {% set mostRecentSermons = mostRecentSermons|merge([sermon]) %}

{% endfor %}
```

If you need to worry about duplicates then you can use `{% if not sermon in mostRecentSermons %}` before merging.

You may also want to wrap this in `{% cache %}{% endcache %}` tags to improve performance.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!